# CSS3 Transform Handle Rectangles Generated

Tags: html, css, transform

I'm trying to create what is essentially a rack using CSS. Here is a demo pen of what I have right now.

http://codepen.io/aherrick/pen/BzrnL

Everything is working as I want it to except for the following. Take a look at the following image as a representation. When the inner rectangles get rendered, they are essentially flipped on the "left" side. This is due to the first rectangle getting rendered at 0,0

Any thoughts on how to combat this while still maintaining a generic method to render the rectangles?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have the "a" and "b" boxes in the left to be swapped.

One way to get that would be to change this

```
.rack .left {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ( -296px );
    -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ( -296px );
    -o-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ( -296px );
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ( -296px );
}
```

to this

```
.rack .left {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ( 296px );
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ( 296px );
    -o-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ( 296px );
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ( 296px );
}
```

(rotate the oposite way)